# Extracting specific metadata like author & date from .doc , .docx

Tags: java, apache-poi, metadata, docx, doc

I am currently trying to extract metadata like the author & the creation-date from .doc, .docx files using the apache poi library. At the moment I only found out how to extract all the metadata in stackoverflow, but not only these specific two. Could somebody please help me?

Comment: Have you tried SummaryInformation? https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hpsf/SummaryInformation.html

Comment: For XWPF: [XWPFDocument.getProperties](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/POIXMLDocument.html#getProperties--) -> [.getCoreProperties](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/POIXMLProperties.html#getCoreProperties--) -> [POIXMLProperties.CoreProperties](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/POIXMLProperties.CoreProperties.html). And for HWPF: [HWPFDocument.getSummaryInformation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/POIDocument.html#getSummaryInformation--) -> [SummaryInformation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hpsf/SummaryInformation.html).

Comment: Thank you both for the answers, it worked perfectly. Does anybody of you know whether this is possible for .txt Files too, or am I right informed that they do not have any metadata in this therms?